# Join tables - Associations in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, associations

For example I have 2 tables: topics and comments.

topic has_many comments. comment belongs_to topic.

Comments table have column sender_id where I save user's id, who create this comment.

Task: Select ids of topics, which is not commented by this user (I know user_id).
(I want to do it with one query).

Earlier I do it so. ( two queries ) ( My database - PostgreSQL)

```
incorrect_topics = Comment.select(:topic_id).where(:sender_id => user_id).map { |elem| elem.topic_id }
ids = select(:id).where(["id NOT IN (?)", incorrect_topics]).map { |elem| elem.id }
```

It works fine, but I suppose that if app become bigger it will be serious problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need are the IDs then you could bypass all the ActiveRecord stuff and do it by hand:

```
ids = connection.select_rows(%Q{
    select id
    from topics
    where id not in (
        select topic_id
        from comments
        where sender_id = #{user_id.to_i}
    )
}).map { |r| r.first.to_i }
```

If you're certain the `user_id` is already an integer then you don't need the `.to_i`. You could also use `#{connection.quote(user_id)}`. You could also use the same SQL with [`select_values`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_values) if you wanted to avoid unwrapping he rows by hand with a `map`.

If you wanted the Topic instances then `find_by_sql` would be an option:

```
topics = find_by_sql(%q{
    select *
    from topics
    where id not in (
        select topic_id
        from comments
        where sender_id = :user_id
    )
}, :user_id => user_id)
```

Some things are clearer when you use straight SQL than when you try to wrap it up in ActiveRecord stuff.

Comment: I didn't try but It have to work. But can I do it not through query in query. but only one query? And can't JOIN help me here? Can JOIN be faster?

Comment: @rusak1: The query optimizer will know what to do with a simple query like that and it has the advantage of being crystal clear.

Comment: And last question: what do you think about JOIN? Is it fast? Is it hard for database?

Comment: and isn't it better to use select_values ?  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_values

Comment: Joins are great and databases are quite good at them. And yes, this would be a good place to use `select_values`.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the reminder about `select_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
incorrect_topics = Comment.where('sender_id <> ?', user_id).topics
```

Let me know if helps you anyway.

Comment: Consider users 1 and 2 that have commented on topic 3, `Comment.where('sender_id <> ?', user_id).topics` will hand you topic 3 even though user 2 has commented on it.

Comment: Kleber S., thank you for variant, but it is incorrect. mu is too short is right.